# Function termination/completeness on Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have a locale `field` and the function `pow_F` defined as follows

```
function (in field)
  pow_F :: "'a ⇒ nat ⇒ 'a" where
  "pow_F x 0 = ONE_F" |
  "pow_F x (Suc n) = x ⋆ (pow_F x n)"
```

where `ONE_F` and `⋆` are the neutral one element and multiplication function defined on the field locale.

This function behaves strangely, since I can't even prove the following

```
lemma (in field) "pow_F x 0 = ONE_F"
```

despite the fact that it follows directly from the definition of `pow_F`. And when I run sledgehammer, the provers either give up or the timer runs out.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `function`, you have to prove termination before you can use the `pow_F.simps` rules. You probably want to use `fun` instead (which proves termination automatically).

Comment: I did prove termination. But you are right, when I use fun or primrec instead of function the problem goes away.

Comment: In that case, feel free to post a more complete minimal example and I will look at what is going on with `function`.

Comment: Most likely you are confusing completeness (the goal required right after the `function`) and termination (where you have to explicitly write `termination` in Isabelle before providing the measure).

Comment: Yes, I had only proved completeness and not termination. Thank you.